# Passing radiobutton value as argument on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I currently have this method:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 
"description,tags,files,editFiles")] Task mydata, int keyId){
```

and I'd like to remove `editFiles` from my `Task` model and modify this method to be:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 
"description,tags,files")] Task mydata, int keyId, string editFiles){
```

My radiobuttons currently look like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.editFiles, "no change", new { @checked = true }) Do not change files
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.editFiles, "delete") Delete old files
```

What is the right way for me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new viewmodel for the edit view, this viewmodel can inherit from the `Task` class.

```
public class EditTaskVM : Task
{
  public bool IsEdit { set;get; }
  //Other edit related properties as needed.
}
```

in your GET action method (For Edit), Return an instance of this new view model, and my Edit view will be strongly typed to this new `EditTaskVM` class

and in the view, use the `IsEdit` property

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsEdit,"nochange", new { @checked = true })No change 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsEdit,"delete") Delete old files
```

For your **HttpPost** action method,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditTaskVM model)
{
  // Do your stuff here
  //check for model.IsEdit
  // TO DO : Redirect (PRG pattern)
}
```